# How do I keep images in programmatrically-created UIButtons from being scaled?

Tags: uibutton

I'm creating a series of UIButtons from an NSArray of UIImages with the following:

```
#define BUTTONWIDTH 66

    for (int i = 0; i < [imgArray count]; i++){
        toolTile = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        buttonRect = CGRectMake((BUTTONWIDTH*i)+i, 0, BUTTONWIDTH, BUTTONWIDTH);
        toolTile.frame = buttonRect;
        toolTile.tag = i;
        [toolTile addTarget:self action:@selector(toolTileClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        toolTile.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        [toolTile setBackgroundImage:[imgArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[self view] addSubview:toolTile];
    }
```

Unfortunately, the images are being scaled (blown up) to fill the 66x66 tile. I want them to be centered at 1:1 in the tile- supposedly `toolTile.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter` should do that. I've tried moving this line before,after the `setBackgroundImage`: -no luck.  What am I missing?

Comment: The culprit was using setBackgroundImage:forState:[UIControlState] instead of setImge:forState:[UIControlState] . SetBackgroundImage apparently always scales, SetImage: honors the imageView.contentMode.

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer and accept the answer, to avoid it cluttering up the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit was using `setBackgroundImage:forState:[UIControlState]` instead of `setImge:forState:[UIControlState]`.

`SetBackgroundImage` apparently always scales, `SetImage:` honors the `imageView.contentMode`.